# OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener not notified after removing entries from SharedPreferences

Tags: android, listview, sharedpreferences, loader

I've been putting together a simple Android ListView app to teach myself LoaderManagers and Loaders. The app simply provides a Loader which is notified when the shared preferences change, via a OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.

It has a simple UI with a ListView and two buttons, one for adding a preference and one for deleting all shared preferences.

My activity is a subclass of ListActivity and implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks>.

My Loader simply notifies the activity when the shared preferences have changed.

My problem is that when the delete all preferences button is clicked, the OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener is not notified, whereas add a preference does notify it. Even though the listener is not notified, the preferences *are* deleted, as a subsequent click on the add preference button updates the list to show a single list entry.

Here's the code (bits omitted for brevity):

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<String>>
{

private ListView listView;
private static final int LOADER_ID = 1;
private LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<String>> mCallbacks;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setUpLoaderManager();

    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void setUpLoaderManager()
{
    mCallbacks = this;
    LoaderManager lm = getLoaderManager();
    lm.initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, mCallbacks);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<String>> loader, List<String> data)
{
    switch (loader.getId())
    {
        case LOADER_ID:
            adapter.clear();
            adapter.addAll(data);
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public Loader<List<String>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args)
{
    return new SampleLoader(this);
}

public void addSharedPreference(View v)
{
    getSharedPreferences("someData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString(new Date().toString(), "hi").commit();
}

public void deleteSharedPreference(View v)
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("someData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    sharedPreferences.edit().clear().commit();
}
```

}

SampleLoader.java

```
public class SampleLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<String>>

{
    private List<String> mData;

public SampleLoader(Context ctx)
{
    super(ctx);
}

@Override
public List<String> loadInBackground()
{
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

    SharedPreferences prefs = getContext().getSharedPreferences("someData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Map<String, String> currentPref = (Map<String, String>) prefs.getAll();

    if (currentPref.size() > 0)
    {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : currentPref.entrySet())
        {
            data.add(entry.getKey());
        }
    }
    return data;
}

@Override
public void deliverResult(List<String> data)
{
    if (isReset())
    {
        releaseResources(data);
        return;
    }

    List<String> oldData = mData;
    mData = data;

    if (isStarted())
    {
        super.deliverResult(data);
    }

    if (oldData != null && oldData != data)
    {
        releaseResources(oldData);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStartLoading()
{
    if (mData != null)
    {
        deliverResult(mData);
    }

    if (mObserver == null)
    {
        mObserver = new SharedPrefsObserver(this, getContext());
    }

    if (takeContentChanged() || mData == null)
    {
        forceLoad();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStopLoading()
{
    cancelLoad();
}

@Override
protected void onReset()
{
    onStopLoading();

    if (mData != null)
    {
        releaseResources(mData);
        mData = null;
    }

    if (mObserver != null)
    {
        mObserver = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCanceled(List<String> data)
{
    super.onCanceled(data);

    releaseResources(data);
}

private void releaseResources(List<String> data)
{
}

private SharedPrefsObserver mObserver;
}
```

SharedPrefsObserver.java

```
public class SharedPrefsObserver
{
    public static OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener;

    public SharedPrefsObserver(final SampleLoader sampleLoader, Context context)
    {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("someData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        listener = new OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
            {
                sampleLoader.onContentChanged();
            }
        };
        prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/button_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_delete"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="deleteSharedPreference"
        android:text="Delete all preferences" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_add"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="addSharedPreference"
        android:text="Add new preference" >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/button_layout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
</ListView>
```

This is the work around I've had to use to force my Loader to refresh the data after deleting a preference:

```
    public void deleteSharedPreference(View v)
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("someData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    sharedPreferences.edit().clear().commit();
    //dirty hack - sharedPreferences observer is not notified when preferences are removed so had to bypass it and call the loader manually
    getLoaderManager().getLoader(LOADER_ID).forceLoad();
}
```

So, any ideas as to why deleting a preference is not notifying my listener?

Comment: Are you sure the listener is not getting notified? It could be that it is getting notified but `sampleLoader.onContentChanged()` is not causing a `forceLoad()`. Add a log statement in `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` to verify.

Comment: There is logging but I removed it to post here. It does not appear in logcat

Comment: Looking at the source at http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java, there is a difference in the implmentation of `remove
()` and `clear()`. It looks like that the listener listens to only `remove()`, not `clear()`.

Comment: Hmm... I tried remove and still had no luck

Comment: `remove(key)` has to work. Use the same key in `remove(key)` that you used in `putString(key,value)`. In your code, i see you have used `new Date().toString()`. Try with some explicit value.

Comment: I retrieved all the keys before removing them individually, but maybe I got something wrong - I'll take another look

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sharedPreferences.edit().clear().commit()` will not notify the listener, by design. You need to use `remove(key)` instead of `clear()` if you want to be notified of a deletion of a shared preference.

Looking at the Android [source](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java#345), you can see that the implementation of `clear()` and `remove(key)` is slightly different. While `remove(key)` adds the key to a private HashMap object that is created by the editor to track changes, `clear()` simply sets a flag and does not make any change to the HashMap object. The SharedPreferences private method [NotifyListeners()](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java#465) does not respect this flag, it only looks at the HashMap object. So calling `clear()` will not be reported by the listener.

**[Edit] :**
When removing keys, you have to use the same `editor` instance to commit it as well :

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("someData", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.remove(myKey1);
editor.remove(myKey2);
...
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Using an explicit value seemed to work with remove("aString").commit(). However, now I'm confused as to why I cannot add new Date().String() as keys and remove them with remove(key) after retrieving the key from the shared prefs. I.e. to add a shared preference:
  getSharedPreferences("someData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString(new Date().toString(), "hi").commit();
  
and to delete them all:
  for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : prefs.entrySet())
  {   sharedPreferences.edit().remove(entry.getKey());
  }
  sharedPreferences.edit().commit();

Comment: Apologies for the formatting above! To explain, I'm getting all the preferences using the getAll() method on Sharedpreferences and iterating over the map, retrieving each key and sending that key to remove and the SharedPreferences seem to think that key doesn't exit. It does as I've just retrieved it!

Comment: Everytime you use `sharedPreferences.edit()...`, you are creating a new `Editor` object. So every `remove(key)` has been done by a different `Editor` object. You have used a new `Editor` to do the `commit()` as well, which has not removed any keys yet. Instead you need to create a single instance of `Editor` before and outside your loop and use that same editor to do all the `remove(key)` and `commit()` at the end.